# GtkEntry don't get keyboard input

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have the following piece of `GTK3` code:

```
(...)
cmd_bar = gtk_entry_new();
gtk_editable_set_editable(GTK_EDITABLE(cmd_bar), TRUE);
gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(cmd_bar), TRUE);
gtk_widget_grab_focus(GTK_WIDGET(cmd_bar));
gtk_grid_attach (GTK_GRID (grid), GTK_WIDGET(cmd_bar), 0, 1, 2, 1);
gtk_widget_show(cmd_bar);
(...)
```

It shows the `GtkEntry` correctly, however it doesn't show any input from keyboard. If I paste some string it's accepted normally.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue. It started occuring when I switched from GTK3 to GTK4. Probably something misconfigured, but I don't know what. I've tried both GtkEntry and GtkTextView with both editable and can-focus set to true without any luck. I've copied code creating a textview from gtk4-demos which works into my application so the code is identical yet it does not work in my app. Otherwise the behavior for me is identical to yours, I can paste but can't focus the entry/textview to input from the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I ported my application from GTK3 to GTK4, same behavior that I was able to paste and cut text in the entry but not being able to focus or freely insert text with my keyboard.

Already in my GTK3 application I had on a few widgets incorrectly set the "can-focus" property to "False" by mistake in my templates (with glade) and when porting to GTK4 they seem to have caused issues.
At first I didn't think the "can-focus" property could be the issue because my GtkEntry had it set to TRUE, the issue was that one of it's **parent containers** had the value set to FALSE.

Hopefully this was the issue for you as well, if it's not hopefully it's an solution for someone else.

Comment: Thanks, your were spot on in my case. This was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [GtkWidget documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-grab-focus):

> `[gtk_widget_grab_focus]` Causes widget to have the keyboard focus for the `GtkWindow` it's
>   inside. `widget` must be a focusable widget, such as a `GtkEntry`;
>   something like `GtkFrame` won't work.
>
> More precisely, it must have the `GTK_CAN_FOCUS` flag set. Use
>   `gtk_widget_set_can_focus()` to modify that flag.
>
> The widget also needs to be realized and mapped. This is indicated by
>   the related signals. **Grabbing the focus immediately after creating the
>   widget will likely fail and cause critical warnings**.

For an explanation of *realize* and *map*, check ["*Those “realize” & “map” widget signals*"](http://blogs.gnome.org/jnelson/2010/10/13/those-realize-map-widget-signals/).